# EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError - SSL3_GET_RECORD: wrong version number (TLS 1.2)

Tags: http, delphi, openssl, indy, indy10

I use Delphi 2010, newest Indy 10.6.2 (5498) and OpenSSL 1.0.2r (from indy.fulgan.com) and I am not able to force it to use TLS 1.2. When I open a page mentioned later, it returns EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError:

> Error connecting with SSL. error:1408F10B:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Here is the code I use to open web

```
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  IdHTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(IdHTTP.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(IdHTTP.IOHandler).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];

    IdHTTP.Get('https://...');
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When I open https:// www.google.com, then it correctly uses TLS 1.2, here are details from Wireshark

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 512
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 508
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
```

But when I open this page https:// www.downloadtb.com, Indy uses TLS 1.0. The site uses TLS 1.2 only and this cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384.

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 329
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 325
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
```

It seems that it mixes TLS 1.0 and 1.2. Is this some kind of fallback? How do I fix it?

EDIT: Something changed on the site and Indy now correctly uses TLS 1.2

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 512
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 508
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
```

Comment: There is no fallback in this case. The handshake clearly shows that the client is using TLS 1.2. It makes perfect sense that you would get an error on sites that do not use TLS 1.2. For a wide compatibility with most sites, you should enable TLS 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2. Not all sites have upgraded to 1.2 yet.

Comment: And FYI, you didn't show the client hello when connected to Google, you showed the server hello instead, which instructs the client which version to use. Had you looked at the client hello, it likely would have looked just like the one you showed for DownloadTB. The client presents the versions it supports, then the server picks one and reports it back.

Comment: Thanks. It seems it was some server side SSL problem. I edited my post - it correctly uses TLS now and it shows "TLSv1.2 Record Layer" as expected. It was "TLSv1 Record Layer" before. Browsers did not have any problem with that. Weird.